# Minecraft fabric coding issues in vscode

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, minecraft, minecraft-fabric

Hey i'm trying to learn how to code minecraft mods in VScode with Fabric mod loader. However I keep running into the same issue, I am unable to open the minecraft testing client. It keeps crashing.
I have tried re-writing all the code I added after the last time I successfully ran it. Here my code:

```
package net.my.first.mod;

import net.fabricmc.api.ModInitializer;
import net.minecraft.item.Item;
import net.minecraft.item.ItemGroup;
import net.minecraft.util.Identifier;
import net.minecraft.util.registry.Registry;
import net.minecraft.block.Block;

public class MyFirstMod implements ModInitializer {

    public static final Item FABRIC_ITEM = new FabricItem(new Item.Settings().group(ItemGroup.MISC), null);

    public static final Block FABRIC_BLOCK = new FabricBlock(new Item.Settings().group(ItemGoup.MISC), null);

    @Override
    public void onInitialize() {
        Registry.register(Registry.ITEM, new Identifier("myfirstmod", "fabric_item"), FABRIC_ITEM);
        Registry.register(Registry.BLOCK, new Identifier("myfirstmod", "fabric_block"), FABRIC_BLOCK);
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance for any help anyone is able to provide!

Comment: You should probably include the call-stack of the crash

Comment: Call stack as in the logs? @UnholySheep

Answer (score 1):

I also had this issue when I first tried making my Fabric mod. Every time I re-open VScode and try to open Minecraft, it crashes. It says something like `cannot find library lwjgl.dll`. For me, `.\gradlew.bat vscode` solved it; I think it's because the assets were messed up or something is wrong in the `.vscode` directory.
Hope it helps ;)

Comment: Also, if you add the crash message it would be better.

Answer (score 0):

I was following the guide from [Setting up Visual Studio Code with Fabric](https://fabricmc.net/wiki/tutorial:vscode_setup), and my problem was the same as described in [The import net.minecraft cannot be resolved](https://www.reddit.com/r/fabricmc/comments/o194er/the_import_netminecraft_cannot_be_resolved/)
.

A mixture of [using `./gradlew --refresh-dependencies`](https://www.reddit.com/r/fabricmc/comments/o194er/comment/h22x351/?context=3), along with [clearing the loom cache](https://github.com/FabricMC/fabric/issues/1281#issuecomment-766438470), `./gradlew clean` and and re-running `./gradlew vscode` seemed to help.